# How to check QtDesigner-generated widget point for validity in QTimer?

Tags: qt, crash

Inside my QDialog code I've got the following:

```
QTimer::singleShot(2 * 1000, [&] {
    if (theme_download_label) {
        theme_download_label->hide();
        theme_download_label->setText("text");
    }
});
```

The issue is that if I close the dialog before the timer fires, `theme_download_label->setText` crashes. How to deal with this?

I've already tried setting `theme_download_label` to `Q_NULLPR` before the `close()` method to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't matter where the widget originates from, or whether it's a widget. The solution is the same for any `QObject`.
2. Provide a `QObject` context to the connection. When the context object dies, it gets disconnected, and thus the functor will not be invoked.
3. Pass the pointer to the label by value, not by reference, in case the timer outlives `this`. That was the likely cause of the crash.
4. There's no need to check whether `theme_download_label` is null: it can't be. That's the invariant of a connection with a context object: it is guaranteed by design that the context object is alive.

   ```
   QTimer::singleShot(2 * 1000, theme_download_label, [label = theme_download_label] {
       label->hide();
       label->setText("text");
   });
   ```